# Differential sync API for OneDrive using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Microsoft has added [differential sync](https://www.windowscentral.com/onedrive-rolls-out-differential-sync-save-you-time-and-data-when-syncing-files) to OneDrive so that the sync client only uploads changes to a file within OneDrive rather than uploading the entire file again. This is very useful since it save a lot of time and bandwidth. I would like to use Microsoft Graph APIs in order to sync the data in my app using Onedrive, so users can access it on multiple platforms. However, in the [APIs provided by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) when a file is modified locally then in order to sync the file in the cloud, the entire file needs to be uploaded again. This is quite time consuming (especially for slow network connections) and wastes unnecessary bandwidth. Is there a way to use differential sync with the Microsoft Graph APIs to solve this issue?